# Trigger checkbox change class in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, triggers

I am new to jQuery. 
I am trying to make a switcher using a checkbox. At the moment I have gone this far

```js
$(function() {
  $('input.cbx').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked", true)) {
      $('body').addClass('dark');
    } else if ($(this).prop("checked", false)) {
      $('.body').addClass('light');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="dn" type="checkbox" class="cbx hidden" />
<label for="dn" class="lbl"></label>
```

As you can see the checkbox stay checked after the first click, I imagine is a noob situation but, can you help me please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are actually setting the checked property instead of getting.

```
$('input.cbx').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).prop("checked") ==  "true")
    {
      $('body').addClass('dark');
    } else if($(this).prop("checked") ==  "false")
    {
        $('.body').addClass('light');
    }
});
```

You can use `this.checked` or `$(this).is(":checked")` instead of `$(this).prop("checked")`

```
$('input.cbx').on('change', function() {
    if(this.checked) 
       $('body').addClass('dark');
    else
       $('.body').addClass('light');        
});
```

You can also use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$('input.cbx').on('change', function() {     
     $('.body').toggleClass('light');        
});
```

Note: I could not see any element with class body? You probably need to assign class to label. If you want to apply the toggle effect to body then remove dot

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8j2fytj0/)**

*HTML*

```
<body class="cbx">
<input id="dn" type="checkbox" class="cbx hidden"/>
      <label for="dn" class="lbl">123</label>
</body>
```

*Javascript*

```
$('input.cbx').on('change', function() {     
     $('body').toggleClass('light');        
});
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, do you have any comprehensible tutorial or article about this? I'd like to understand the  if(this.checked) synthax

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.cbx').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert('checked');
    } else {
        alert('not checked');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ztrLjzav/)
You can check if the checkbox is check using `$(this).is(":checked")`